# Volley, JsonArrayRequest OnResponse Not Calling

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to parse json array, but JsonArrayRequest OnResponse method Not Calling. So my list of albums returns null. I searched in the internet, but I couldn't solve the problem.

Here is my code:

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {
View rootView;
ListView listView;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listfragment, container, false);

    listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    new ListAsync(getActivity(), listView).execute();

    return rootView;
}

private class ListAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog progressDialog_dunya;
    String urlAlbum = "http://www.jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums";
    ListView mListView;
    Activity mContex;
    int userid, id;
    String title;
    MyListAdapter myListAdapter;
    List<Album> albums;
    Album album;

    ListAsync(Activity contex, ListView gview)
    {
        this.mListView=gview;
        this.mContex=contex;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog_dunya = new ProgressDialog(mContex);
        progressDialog_dunya.setTitle("Yükleniyor...");
        progressDialog_dunya.setMessage("Yükleniyor...");
        progressDialog_dunya.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog_dunya.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("RESPONSE ALBUM", "hey" + urlAlbum);
        albums = getJsonAlbum();
        Log.d("RESPONSE ALBUM", "hey al" + albums);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter(mContex, albums);
        mListView.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
        progressDialog_dunya.dismiss();
    }

    List<Album> getJsonAlbum(){
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        Log.d("RESPONSE ALBUM", "IN GETJSON");
        JsonArrayRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(
                urlAlbum, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE ALBUM", "response"+response.toString());
                try {

                    albums = new ArrayList<Album>();


                    for (int i = 0; i< response.length();i++) {

                        album = new Album();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                        userid = jsonObject.getInt("userId");
                        id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                        title = jsonObject.getString("title");

                        album.setId(id);
                        album.setTitle(title);
                        album.setUserId(userid);

                        albums.add(album);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("volley", "error");
            }
        });

        requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);

        return albums;

    }
    }
    }
```

Here is my log:

```
D/RESPONSE ALBUM: heywww.jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums
D/RESPONSE ALBUM: IN GETJSON
D/RESPONSE ALBUM: hey alnull
```

Comment: `JsonArrayRequest` already execute call in worker Thread so no need to use `AsyncTask`

Comment: volley take time , won't return result response instantly , no need of asynch so just call this function `getJsonAlbum()` and move your setting adapter code in some function and call it at the end of `onresponse`

Comment: Thank you, solved the issue.

Comment: @PavneetSingh 's comment did.

Comment: i am glad , i could help and you did it , happy coding